# Angular Wont update the DOM but logs the data to console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Do you know why wont Angularjs update the div. However I am able to log the data to console.

What am I missing here?

I have added a fiddle;

```
function jsonp_example($scope, $http) {
    $scope.doRequest = function() {
        var url = "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

        $http.jsonp(url)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data.found);
            });
    };

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a4Rc2/850/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the result data to scope variable:

```
$http.jsonp(url).success(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log(data.found);
});
```

Otherwise Angular has no idea that you want this response data to be displayed anywhere.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a4Rc2/853/

Comment: how did I miss that. ah:) but actually my json is repeating through items as item in data.items. In that case do I need to do  $scope.data = data.items;?

Comment: if you use `ng-repeat="item in data.items"` then it still should be `$scope.data = data`.

Comment: Thanks. hey do you know what do I need to do to set the value of an input type text as ng-model via a directive. I am able to create a directive but not sure how do I set the value of input type="text". The value is a random no.

Comment: If that was unclear, can you guide me in the right direction here?
http://jsbin.com/xelerusu/1/edit

I need the value returned by function inside my text box via angular

Comment: @Mike Something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/0F6scX7ARHJSQfLriDGi?p=preview)?

Comment: hi can you help me with this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976537/how-do-i-get-an-id-that-is-part-of-a-url-in-angularjs-i-am-using-restangular-t