# How do I get an ID that is part of a URL, in angularjs? I am using Restangular to communicate with REST API's

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, restangular

I am using Restangular to make backend calls and everything works fine as long as URL gives me data like below:

If I hit
`http://mysite/responses/` the responses look like

```
[
    {"fname":"some guy",
     "lname":"some name",
     "dob":2091,
     "job":"mgr",
     "id":"100"
     },
     {"fname":"another guy",
     "lname":"anpther name",
     "dob":1991,
     "job":"worker",
     "id":"101"
     },
     {"fname":"someone",
     "lname":"some name",
     "dob":1997,
     "job":"dev",
     "id":"102"
     },
     {"fname":"some guy2",
     "lname":"some name",
     "dob":2091,
     "job":"sec",
     "id":"103"
     }
]
```

and everything works fine

which is wrapped in an array and my Restangular URL looks like

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://mysite/responses/');
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({ id: 'id' });
```

and it works all fine

Now I deconstructed the backend and API returns the data in below format

`http://mysite/responses/100`

```
{
    fname:"some guy",
     lname:"some name",
     dob:2091,
     job:"mgr",
     id:"100"
}
```

`http://mysite/responses/101`

```
{
    fname:"another guy",
     lname:"another name",
     dob:1991,
     job:"sec",
     id:"101"
}
```

`http://mysite/responses/102`

```
{
    fname:"some name",
     lname:"some person",
     dob:1091,
     job:"sec",
     id:"102"
}
```

`http://mysite/responses/103`

```
{
    fname:"a guy",
     lname:"person name",
     dob:1998,
     job:"dev",
     id:"103"
}
```

Now if I hit

`http://mysite/responses/`

I get below responses

```
http://mysite/responses/100
http://mysite/responses/101
http://mysite/responses/102
http://mysite/responses/103
http://mysite/responses/104
```

As you see, the id is getting appended to the url, and I need to get this id, make an Restangular call and get the data. How can I loop through this multiple http calls, get the id and put it in Angular. I think I am not constructing the BaseURl for Restanglar properly, because I am not sure how to get the id. 
thanks for the help

Comment: I don't think I understand. You want to make it so that when the user navigates to http://mysite/responses/, your code queries the other 5 endpoints?

Comment: That's is how the current backend is set up? What is the alternative.

Comment: Do you know that it is always responses 100-104? Because in the question you said you need to "get the id and put it in Angular"... Because if you are just wanting to loop through 5 restangular calls it's pretty simple...

Comment: @NevilleS: I need to format BaseURl for Restangular, I need id and I am not able to get that id, because I can't use routeParams

Comment: Why not just use javascript? `"http://mysite/responses/103".split("/").pop()` will give you "103". Or didn't I understand?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `routeParams`:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

This is used together with routes:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

For example:

```
$routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId', {
    templateUrl: 'book.html',
    controller: function($scope, $routeParams) {
        console.log($routeParams.bookId);
    })
});
```

Comment: I cant access routeParams in BaseUrl of Restangular?

Comment: are you using routes at all?